# 400 no matching index found with single order

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-firestore, datastore

I'm not able to create a query with a single filter (Cloud Firestore in Native mode):

```
query = cls._client.query(kind="parcel_center")
query.add_filter('error', '=', True)
query.keys_only();
query_iter = query.fetch(limit=5)
page = next(query_iter.pages)
```

I'm getting "400 no matching index found." error without recommendations for creating index. What is wrong?

Comment: Could you share how are your objects conformed? and which firestore mode are you using?

Comment: I'm using DataStore mode. tile_versions http://prntscr.com/qiedqw

Comment: Could you share more code, to see the part where you are calling next?

Comment: It throws exception just while query.fetch()